# What .dll files do I need in order to get QtSql to run properly?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I created a Windows Qt C++ application that performs some SQL queries. This application compiled and runs correctly on my development machine.

I have these directories in my PATH environment variable:

> C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin
>   C:\instantclient_11_2
>   C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin
>   C:\Qt\4.7.4\bin

I would like to distribute my application as a standalone to other computers so I have included these .dll files with the distribution:

> QtCore4.dll
>   QtGui4.dll
>   QtSql4.dll
>   qsqloci4.dll
>   mingwm10.dll
>   libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

This is how my QSqlDatabase is setup in my code:

```
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI");
    db.setHostName(hostname);
    db.setPort(port);
    db.setDatabaseName(sid);
    db.setUserName(username);
    db.setPassword(password);
    bool ok = db.open();
    if (ok) {
        //stuff
    } else {
        QString dbErr = db.lastError().databaseText();
        QString drErr = db.lastError().driverText();
        return this->messageBox("SQL Query Failed:\n" + dbErr + "\n" + drErr);
    }
```

When I run this application on a computer that is not my development machine, dbErr and drErr are set to "Driver not loaded". What other .dll files do I need in order to get this to run correctly?

Edit:

Do I need oci.dll from C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin?
What about oci.dll from C:\instantclient_11_2?

I tried adding both of those files to my executable's directory, but I still get the same error. Do I need both of those .dll files somehow?

Comment: Where is qsqloci4.dll located with respect to your exe? Could you try putting it in a subdirectory "plugins/sqldrivers"? It might still look for this standard path instead of directly in the same dir as your exe.

Comment: I tried putting qsqloci4.dll in executable_dir/plugins/sqldrivers and I still get the same error. I added a comment about oci.dll in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a folder call `sqldrivers` in the directory containing your exe. Put all the SQL driver DLLs you are using in there (qsqloci4.dll).

See [How to Create Qt Plugins - Locating Plugins](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/plugins-howto.html#locating-plugins) for more information on using Qt plugins and how Qt finds them.